# Matching Dataframe Values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working on a project that requires me to match two data frames based on two separate columns, X and Y.

e.g.

df1 =

```
|  X  |  Y  | AGE |
|:--- |:---:|----:|
| 20  | 15  | 25  |
| 10  | 05  | 29  |
| 15  | 00  | 21  |
| 20  | 20  | 32  |
| 00  | 15  | 19  |
```

df2 =

```
|  X  |  Y  | AGE |
|:--- |:---:|----:|
| 00  | 00  | []  |
| 00  | 05  | []  |
| 00  | 10  | []  |
| 00  | 15  | []  |
| 00  | 20  | []  |
| 05  | 00  | []  |
| 05  | 05  | []  |
| 05  | 10  | []  |
| 05  | 15  | []  |
| 05  | 20  | []  |
| 10  | 00  | []  |
| 10  | 05  | []  |
| 10  | 10  | []  |
| 10  | 15  | []  |
| 10  | 20  | []  |
| 15  | 00  | []  |
| 15  | 05  | []  |
| 15  | 10  | []  |
| 15  | 15  | []  |
| 15  | 20  | []  |
| 20  | 00  | []  |
| 20  | 05  | []  |
| 20  | 10  | []  |
| 20  | 15  | []  |
| 20  | 20  | []  |
```

The goal is to sort through df1, find the row with its matching coordinates in df2, and then store the AGE value from df1 in the AGE list in df2. The code I have so far is:

```
for n in df1:
    if int(df1["X"].values[n]) == int(df2["X"].values[n]):
        for m in df1:
            if int(df1["Y"].values[m]) == int(df2["Y"].values[m]):
                df2['AGE'].push(df1['AGE'])
```

The expected output would be:

df2 =

```
|  X  |  Y  | AGE |
|:--- |:---:|----:|
| 00  | 00  | []  |
| 00  | 05  | []  |
| 00  | 10  | []  |
| 00  | 15  |[19] |
| 00  | 20  | []  |
| 05  | 00  | []  |
| 05  | 05  | []  |
| 05  | 10  | []  |
| 05  | 15  | []  |
| 05  | 20  | []  |
| 10  | 00  | []  |
| 10  | 05  |[29] |
| 10  | 10  | []  |
| 10  | 15  | []  |
| 10  | 20  | []  |
| 15  | 00  |[21] |
| 15  | 05  | []  |
| 15  | 10  | []  |
| 15  | 15  | []  |
| 15  | 20  | []  |
| 20  | 00  | []  |
| 20  | 05  | []  |
| 20  | 10  | []  |
| 20  | 15  |[25] |
| 20  | 20  |[32] |
```

Comment: what about right join? `pd.merge(df1, df2, on= ['X', 'Y'], how='right')`

Comment: the merge is the correct answer, but I have a feeling you want to include matches within a range of co-ordinates. can you include your expected output?

Comment: There's some data manipulation happening to the actual df1 values that make this harder to do (the actual values are floats and we are rounding the values, hence passing the values using int()), plus we want to keep X and Y separate so that we can graph them.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a left-join matching both X & Y based on `df2`. And I just read that you need both columns X & Y to be integers. And not sure if I understood the need to preserve the original X & Y values to "graph them". Here's a possible way:

```
for col in ['X', 'Y']:
    df1[col+'1'] = df1[col].astype('int')
    df2[col+'1'] = df2[col].astype('int')

print(pd.merge(df2, df1[['AGE', 'X1', 'Y1']], how='left', on=['X1', 'Y1']))
```

Output:

```
     X   Y  X1  Y1  AGE
0   00  00   0   0  NaN
1   00  05   0   5  NaN
2   00  10   0  10  NaN
3   00  15   0  15   19
4   00  20   0  20  NaN
5   05  00   5   0  NaN
6   05  05   5   5  NaN
7   05  10   5  10  NaN
8   05  15   5  15  NaN
9   05  20   5  20  NaN
10  10  00  10   0  NaN
11  10  05  10   5   29
12  10  10  10  10  NaN
13  10  15  10  15  NaN
14  10  20  10  20  NaN
15  15  00  15   0   21
16  15  05  15   5  NaN
17  15  10  15  10  NaN
18  15  15  15  15  NaN
19  15  20  15  20  NaN
20  20  00  20   0  NaN
21  20  05  20   5  NaN
22  20  10  20  10  NaN
23  20  15  20  15   25
24  20  20  20  20   32
```

Comment: hi @PurpleSky  is my suggestion able to answer your question?